# How to define an application for the command prompt?

Tags: command-line, powershell

How would I define an application for the command prompt? When I type [calc into the command prompt and press enter it will show it on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ydvc.png). However, when I input [CHROME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVbGw.png) into the command line it doesn't work. Could someone please walk me through what to do next.

Comment: you will have to put the path to the chrome.exe into your environment path variable https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome will not run unless it is in your path. Possible solutions are:-

- Find Chrome's directory from its launch link and add it to your path.
- Add `chrome.cmd` to a directory in your path, containing:
  `@echo off`
  `PathToChrome\chrome.exe`
- Set up an alias with [DosKey](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html):
  `doskey chrome=PathToChrome\chrome.exe`
  You can make this permanent by adding it to a [CMD start-up script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/5164855).

Comment: I like it. But going forward. How would I define the variable `PathToChrome`? I have been persuing the registry.

Comment: It's not a variable; it's a meta-string used to illustrate my answer: you replace it with the path that you retrieve from the properties of the link used to launch Chrome. If it were a variable, I would have used `%PathToChrome%`.

Comment: `if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Application\chrome.exe" doskey chrome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Application\chrome.exe"`

Comment: `chrome http://molddocs/?moldid=12`

Comment: If I ran the code above, it should work all in 1 instance?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Have you tried it and it hasn't worked?